# How to read input byte array in chunks in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, buffer, arrays, mp4

How could we implement to read mp4 video data as chunked byte arrays which is shown below is sends all byte buffer at the same time?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnUploadLocal').on('click', function () {

    var files = $("#file1").get(0).files;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var rawData = reader.result;

            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://x.x.x.x:8080/movefile",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: rawData
        });

        ajaxRequest.error(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it now using slice command;

```
 var chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
```